# Inheritance and pointers in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have this code example and I want to understand why it behaves the way it does. This is a question from a past exam paper in an intro C++ course. I'm studying for the exam now and trying to solidify my understanding of class inheritance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bird {
  public:
    virtual void noise() { cout << "mumble" << endl; }
    void move() { noise(); cout << "fly" << endl; }
};

class Canary: public Bird {
  public:
    void noise() { cout << "chirp" << endl; }
    void move() { noise(); cout << "flap" << endl; }
};

class Tweety: public Canary {
  public:
    void noise() { cout << "tweet" << endl; }
    void move() { noise(); cout << "run" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Canary *yellow = new Tweety();
    yellow->noise();
    yellow->move();
    return 0;
}
```

I've run this code, and the output is:

tweet
tweet
flap

Which means it's calling the *Tweety* implementation of noise(), but it's calling the *Canary* implementation of move(). I'm confused about that. I understand the idea of polymorphism, and noise() is virtual, so it makes sense that it calls the Tweety version, since *yellow is a pointer to a Tweety. But why does it call the Canary version of move()?

I think what's confusing me, is the line:

```
Canary *yellow = new Tweety();
```

This says that *yellow is a Canary pointer, which points to a Tweety object. I'm sort of ok with that, because I get that pointers to base class can point to derived class. But *yellow points to a Tweety, so why doesn't it use Tweety's move()?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This example has no multiple inheritance. To unserstand the behaviour you need to understand the difference between virtual and non-virtual member functions.

Comment: You are calling `move` on a `Canary` pointer and `move` is not virtual on a `Canary`.

Comment: I did not know birds "mumble"

Comment: A good C++ book should explain that. Get one!

Comment: No body see memory leak ?

Answer (score 6):

`noise` is virtual, so it is dynamically dispatched to the `Tweety` implementation when you call it.

`move` in not virtual, so the version to call is decided at compile time based on the type of you are dispatching the call through. Since `yellow` is a `Canary` the compiler does resolve what will be called at compile time and will explicitly call the `move` method in `Canary`.

Comment: +1. Minor thing: I'd replace *"the compiler can resolve"* with *"the compiler does resolve"* - since this is not optional, butrequired behavior.

Comment: Follow-up/clarify question: if yellow is a Canary, then why doesn't the virtual function move call the Canary implementation of move? You're saying that the pointer type determines the implementation for non-virtual functions, but _what the pointer points to_ determines it for virtual functions? And that's because of how virtual works with the compiler, i.e. dynamic dispatch as you called it?

Comment: @Jack - `yellow` has a static type of `Canary`. Because you're calling via a pointer then polymorphism will apply to any virtual function you call. `noise` is a virtual function so it resolves to the implementation in `Tweety` as that's what `yellow` points to. `move` isn't virtual so it's resolved statically. This means the compiler looks at the static type of `yellow` (a `Canary`) and calls the `move` function in `Canary`. If you want it to be dynamically resolved at runtime you'd have to make `move` virtual.

Answer (score 1):

The `move()` should also be `virtual` otherwise the version of the pointer type is called.

Answer (score 0):

Sean and Alex are spot on.

Here are some more call cases that should help make sense of the different scenarios.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bird {
  public:
    virtual void noise() { cout << "mumble" << endl; }
    void move() { noise(); cout << "fly" << endl; }

    void noise2() { cout << "mumble2" << endl; }
    virtual void move2() { noise2(); cout << "fly2" << endl; }
};

class Canary: public Bird {
  public:
    void noise() { cout << "chirp" << endl; }
    void move() { noise(); cout << "flap" << endl; }

    void noise2() { cout << "chirp2" << endl; }
    void move2() { noise2(); cout << "flap2" << endl; }
};

class Tweety: public Canary {
  public:
    void noise() { cout << "tweet" << endl; }
    void move() { noise(); cout << "run" << endl; }

    void noise2() { cout << "tweet2" << endl; }
    void move2() { noise2(); cout << "run2" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Canary *yellow = new Tweety();
    yellow->noise();
    yellow->move();
    yellow->noise2();
    yellow->move2();
    return 0;
}

/* OUTPUT:
tweet    <- virtual dispatch
tweet    <- virtual dispatch, via Bird::move()
flap     <- direct call
chirp2   <- direct call
tweet2   <- direct call, from Tweety::move2()
run2     <- virtual dispatch
*/
```